# excel roundup if number is 2 or greater and/or less than 2

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel I am using the following formula to round off numbers to 0.5:

```
=IF((ROUNDUP(F5,1))-(ROUNDDOWN(F5,0))>0.5,ROUNDUP(F5,0),ROUNDDOWN(F5,0)+0.5)
```

The issue I have is, I would like the formula to see any values of '2' or greater to round up to the next '0' rather than '0.5'. For example, 1.25 rounds up to 1.5 & 2.11 rounds up to 3.

I would appreciate anyone's assistance here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CEILING Function is best in this situation , it allows for significance of the roundup, 
2 of them coupled with an IF will sort this out

```
=IF(F5<2,CEILING(F5,0.5),CEILING(F5,1))
```

Comment: Thank-you for responding. 0.9 would round up to 1. and 1.29 round up to 1.5. However I would like anything 2 and above to round up to the next number not .5 eg: 2.11 rounds up to 3.00 and 4.01 rounds up to 5.00.

Comment: then the formula above i have written will do this for you

Comment: Spot on Steven! Thanks so much :) I really appreciate this!

Comment: What if I want anything between 0.01 and 0.5 to be rounded up to 1? Is there anything else I can add to the formula? This formula currently rounds (0.01 - 0.5) to 0.5

Comment: so 0-0.5 should be rounded to 1 ,0.51-1.99 should be rounded to the nearest 0.5 and >2 should be rounded to the nearest 1 again?

Comment: If possible 0.01-0.5 rounded to 1. and the rest you have is correct 0.51-1.99 should be rounded to the nearest 0.5 and >2 should be rounded to the nearest 1

Comment: =IF(AND(F5>0.5,F5<2),CEILING(F5,0.5),CEILING(F5,1))